# Is it safe to manually delete entries from Java Servlet session database?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, amazon-web-services, servlets

I'm trying to prevent multiple active logins from the same user account simultaneously using a session-based login with a Java servlet (3.x) environment in a cluster. I'm using Tomcat 8 with [this official AWS library](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-tomcat-session-manager.html) that implements a session manager that persists sessions using DynamoDB for storage.

The session manager setup is fairly simple, only requiring that a DynamoDB table be setup before-hand with a hash key called `sessionId` and no range key (or the library can create the table for you if you want).

In order to prevent multiple active logins from the same user account simultaneously, during the login process I would like to somehow query for any active sessions for the particular user that's trying to login. Since the servlet framework does not allow querying by session ID, the best way that I can think of at the moment to accomplish this is to add an additional indexed attribute to the DynamoDB table (the session database) to store the user name for the session, and add that attribute to the session data when the session is created e.g. `HttpSession#setAttribute(String, String)`

Then, when someone tries to login, I can query DynamoDB for any current sessions that match the specified user name. If I get a match, then I can delete that session from DynamoDB and create a new one. So, when someone is already logged in from another machine (or a different browser on the same machine), that session will be invalidated and the new login session will be the only active one.

My question here is whether or not this is appropriate. I'm concerned that I'm sort of bypassing the session manager if I delete entries from the session database myself, so I don't know if this will cause problems. When I delete the sessions myself, I won't be invalidating the sessions in the normal way i.e. calling `HttpSession#invalidate()` Is this approach OK, or is there some other way that I can instruct the session manager (or trigger it) to invalidate the sessions?

In relation to the proposed solution by @ramp in the comments (using an additional attribute that marks sessions as being stale) that raises another question. Is is safe to manually add/update an attribute for a session database entry? Can I safely read a manually added session attribute later e.g. `HttpSession#getAttribute(String)`

Comment: Rather than deleting the older session, why not just mark it as stale (where stale is another indexed attribute) ? And then when the user accesses the stale session, you call HttpSession.invalidate() with appropriate messaging and send the user out ?

Comment: @ramp I really like that solution. It's not a big deal to add another attribute to the table. I think I'll go with that, it sounds safer. Although, I'm still curious as to whether or not manually deleting entries from the session database is safe versus calling `invalidate()`. I'll investigate the source to see what invalidate is doing.

Comment: Invoking HTTPSession.invalidate is needed in many cases. You invoke the method when you want to explicitly clear out the user session.

Comment: @Shibashis Do you know if calling invalidate simply deletes the session database entry? Are there any other implications e.g. local caches

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by local caches, it should clean the HTTP session for the user on the instance where the request got processed and it should delete the entry backed in the database.